# What is the problem with this haystack needle function

Tags: haskell

I inspired myself of a function I found on this site, which counts the occurences of words in a String. Here is the code:

```
import Data.Text (pack, count)

occurences haystack needles = map function needles
     where 
        packed = pack haystack 
        function needle = (count (pack needle) packed, needle)
```

The result of the command

```
occurences ("Hi how are you") ["Hi", "how" , "are", "yo"]
```

gives

```
[(1,"Hi"),(1,"how"),(1,"are"),(1,"yo")]
```

Whereas it should give

```
[(1,"Hi"),(1,"how"),(1,"are"),(0,"yo")]
```

Since yo != you

How could I change my method to make it work as intended?

Ps: Another solution I tried which makes the same mistake is this one:

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, tails)

yourFunction :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [(Int, [a])]
yourFunction haystack = map (count &&& id)
  where count needle = length . filter (needle `isPrefixOf`) . tails $ haystack
```

Comment: It does not look at the words. It simply looks how many times the substring `yo` can be found in the string, and that is one time.

Comment: And how would you go about looking at the word? I guess the problem in the second function is the method `isPrefixOf`, but there doesn't seems to have a function that specifically check for the whole word in Data.List.

Comment: Your question would be *much* easier to read if you gave `occurences` a type signature. Side note: the word is spelled "occurrences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for strict substrings when you seem to want to check full words. Haskell includes the [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) function which splits a string up into individual words. You can use that to produce a function that does what you want:

```hs
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

occursWord :: String -> [String] -> [(Int, String)]
occursWord haystack = map (count &&& id)
    where wordlist = words haystack
          count n = length . filter (== n) $ wordlist
```

Because `words` only operates on `String` instead of on `[a]`, the type of `occurrences` must be specialized to also only operate on `String`s. (This makes sense, though, since list of numbers can't contain a space to split on. Daniel Wagner mentions in comments that there's also [`Data.Text.words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:words) which operates on the `Text` type.)

The output of this function:

```
> occursWord "Hi how are you" ["Hi","how","are","yo"]
[(1,"Hi"),(1,"how"),(1,"are"),(0,"yo")]
```

Comment: There is a [variant of `words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:words) for `Text`.

Comment: Sure. What I was getting at though was that there's no general-case `words` that operates on `[a]` because that concept doesn't make sense for reasons I mentioned.

Comment: Ah. I had completely glossed over their `Eq a => [a] -> ...` version in my first reading. Apologies.